# How to change a video resolution?

Tags: video

Can I change a video resolution (say, from 640x480 to 320x240)?

UPDATE:

At ubuntuforums there's a [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=926227) talking about [avidemux](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php), I did a search in the wiki for "[resolution](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?do=search&id=resolution)" but I found nothing about how to change it. Does anyone use it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### [ffmpeg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ffmpeg)

**[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)** (or `avconv` if ffmpeg was not available) can do this easily

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpeg -s 320x240 output.mpeg
```

There are felt one million [additional options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ffmpeg) to change the output format. These can also be combined

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 320x240 output.mpeg
```

Comment: Thanks! I did a search for "resolution", but I see now it's called "size" in the ffmpeg manual! =)

Comment: It's indeed a pain to read the lengthy ffmpeg documentation, mainly because you can do so much with this brilliant tool (you almost forget it has no GUI) ;)

Comment: It has winFF, but it don't work so well..

Comment: @Takkat I have to use "-c copy", but in other side I want to resize screen. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde: changing the geometry needs the video to be re-encoded. We can not copy the video content (but we can copy the audio tracs).